# Index ActionResult returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Please find below my ActionResult Index:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SectionText)
{

    var products = from p in db.Products
                   where p.CategoryID == SectionText
                   //orderby gs.SortBy
                   select p;

    return View(products.ToList());
}
```

This is throwing the error below: -

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL:
>   /Sections/daughterboards-894/

Any Ideas would be much appreciated. this is using the built in vs web server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are requesting `/Sections/daughterboards-894` and there's nothing that would relate this url to the `Index` action. If you are using the default routes your request should look like this: `/sections/index/daughterboards-894`

Of course this assumes that you have a route capable of handling this URL:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{SectionText}",
    new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        SectionText = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

If you want to have an url like `/Sections/daughterboards-894/` you will need to set a special route for it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MySpecialUrl",
    "Sections/{SectionText}",
    new { 
        controller = "Sections", 
        action = "Index", 
        SectionText = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

Remark: As a side note I would recommend you abstracting your data access into a repository instead of directly accessing it in your controllers. This will make your code much easier to unit test.

Comment: Thanks i added the route but this didnt have the desired effect and im still getting the same error

Comment: Just an update this link here works but if i remove the index it doesnt. however Index is specifield as the default option

http://localhost:21063/Sections/Index/firewalls-hardware-832 - works
http://localhost:21063/Sections/firewalls-hardware-832 - doesnt work...

Comment: Thanks I figured it out the new route works but i needed to put it before the default route school boy error!